# How to set cmd window's icon in cmd - windows 7

Tags: batch-file, cmd, windows-7

How can i set cmd window's icon using a .bat file(if there isn't a way It's good for me to set it from settings or anything), but only the window's icon on windows 7.

Comment: Hi, is about the icon on left side of windows opened from cmd when running a bat file? Sorry my English..

Comment: Place your icon resources into a `.dll` file, and point `cmd.exe`, _or your batch file shortcut, `.lnk`_ to the particular icon you wish within the `.dll` file. Please note, _(although not relevant to your provided OS)_, that from `Windows 10` onwards, I believe that the `.dll` must be located in `\Windows\System32` for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

> 1) try using the "[Bat To Exe Converter](http://www.f2ko.de/en/b2e.php)" and adding a icon to the file.bat to file.exe

[image]

> 2) or, make a shortcut to bat, and add a icon to this shortcut, but, copy the ico to this relative path ( like %temp% or %APPDATA%) and call the bat by this shortcut with relative path set to icon...

set icon in this shortcut, by adding this path "%temp%\My_Icon.ico" and call the link to run a bat, see how and the results in pictures...

[image]
[image]